# Обсуждение IT новостей в чате - политота?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, чат, модераторский-произвол

Не то, чтобы я удивлён, но давно ли обсуждение тем, которые нас всех касаются, связанных с IT, в чате стало политотой?

Собственно, [вот 6 сообщений](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48574753#48574753), которые были перенесены. Тему, непосредственно связанную с IT и интернетом, нельзя обсуждать в основном чате? Давно?

1. В ответ на просьбу о возврате сообщений в чат получил лишь ёрничество.
2. Это неуместное сообщение было помечено тревогой, после чего был закономерный бан в чате на 30 минут.
3. Бан был снят другим модератором через пару минут(?!).

Comment: Пора альтчат расчехлять. Без произвола. Или овнерства лишать снова :)

Comment: @älёxölüt глядя на то, что бан сняли сразу же, то овнерства своих лишать никто не станет явно.

Comment: Кстати, а что значит "другим" в п.3? Там несколько ромбов было?

Comment: @älёxölüt я заметил, как на пару секунд в чат зашёл тот, кого нельзя называть, после этого бан был снят. Он ли снял бан или нет, я не знаю.

Comment: @älёxölüt политоту можно сразу там начинать обсуждать.

Comment: Интересно, не вижу в твоём профиле чата банов за 2019 год...

Comment: @Qwertiy так не меня забанили, а модератора, а потом его резво разбанили.

Comment: @Suvitruf вообще не понял. Кого там банили-то в итоге?

Comment: @älёxölüt модератор запостил неуместную картинку. Её зафлагали. Модератор получил бан (насколько я понимаю, автоматический). Пришёл другой модератор и разбанил.

Comment: кто это тот, кого нельзя называть?

Comment: @michael_best на этот вопрос нельзя так ответ. Догадайтесь, почему ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тему, непосредственно связанную с IT и интернетом, обсуждать в основном чате можно.

Для тем связанных с политикой существует отдельный чат.

В перенесенных сообщениях два было со ссылками, в одно больше политики чем новостей IT, во второй просто одна политика.

Поэтому перенес всю ветку сразу.

Comment: 1/6 сообщений - политота, поэтому перенесли большую часть сообщений? А что скажете по поводу бана? Александра на вас нет.

Comment: @Suvitruf, если бы перенес только одно (на самом деле два) то контекст бы потерялся

Comment: @Suvitruf, _А что скажете по поводу бана_  ничего не скажу, был на 20 минут, потом вдруг пропал.